# OpenGL MVP Matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, transform, projection, perspective

I am simply trying to upgrade my code from OpenGL 1 to a new version which uses VBO and GLSL. I am trying to calculate the MVP matrix but I seem to have run into a snag. As far as I know I am calculating this correctly wrt RH system. I would like to know where it is I am going wrong?

```
void lookAt(Vector4f& eye, Vector4f& viewPoint, Vector4f& up) {
    _viewMatrix.setIdentity();

    Vector4f zaxis;
    zaxis = eye - viewPoint;    // forward vector
    zaxis.normalize();
    Vector4f xaxis;
    xaxis = up.cross(zaxis);    // right vector
    xaxis.normalize();
    Vector4f yaxis;
    yaxis = zaxis.cross(xaxis);

    /* OPTOMIZED APPROACH */
    _viewMatrix.mat[0][0] = xaxis.x;        _viewMatrix.mat[0][1] = yaxis.x;        _viewMatrix.mat[0][2] = zaxis.x;
    _viewMatrix.mat[1][0] = xaxis.y;        _viewMatrix.mat[1][1] = yaxis.y;        _viewMatrix.mat[1][2] = zaxis.y;
    _viewMatrix.mat[2][0] = xaxis.z;        _viewMatrix.mat[2][1] = yaxis.z;        _viewMatrix.mat[2][2] = zaxis.z;
    _viewMatrix.mat[0][3] = -(xaxis * eye); _viewMatrix.mat[1][3] = -(yaxis * eye); _viewMatrix.mat[2][3] = -(zaxis * eye);
}

perspective(float& FOV, float& aspect, float& nearDistance, float& farDistance) {
    _projectionMatrix.setIdentity();

    float rad = 3.1415926f / 180.0f;

    float top = nearDistance * std::tan((FOV * rad) / 2);
    float bottom = -top;
    float right = top * aspect;
    float left = -right;

    _projectionMatrix.mat[0][0] = (2 * nearDistance) / (right - left);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[1][1] = (2 * nearDistance) / (top - bottom);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[2][2] = -(farDistance + nearDistance) / (farDistance - nearDistance);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[2][3] = (-2 * farDistance * nearDistance) / (farDistance - nearDistance);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[0][2] = (right + left) / (right - left);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[1][2] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    _projectionMatrix.mat[3][2] = -1;
    _projectionMatrix.mat[3][3] = 0;
}
```

The Method for sending the data

```
glewInit();
    _shader = ShaderManager::getInstance().addShader(vert, frag);
    glUseProgram(_shader.programID);
    /*  PROJECTION LOCATION */
    _program_Projection_Location = glGetUniformLocation(_shader.programID, "projection");
    if (_program_Projection_Location == -1) {
        ErrorMessage error{
            "Window",
            "initializeShaders",
            "Projection pointer location returned -1",
            false
        };
        Logger::getInstance().addLog(error);
    }
    _program_View_Location = glGetUniformLocation(_shader.programID, "view");
    if (_program_View_Location == -1) {
        ErrorMessage error{
            "Window",
            "initializeShaders",
            "View Matrix pointer location returned -1",
            false
        };
        Logger::getInstance().addLog(error);
    }
    /*  MODEL LOCATION */
    _program_Model_Location = glGetUniformLocation(_shader.programID, "model");
    if (_program_Model_Location == -1) {
        ErrorMessage error{
            "Window",
            "initializeShaders",
            "Model Matrix pointer location returned -1",
            false
        };
        Logger::getInstance().addLog(error);
    }
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_program_Projection_Location, 1, GL_FALSE, &_projectionMatrix.mat[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_program_View_Location, 1, GL_FALSE, &_viewMatrix.mat[0][0]);
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: What is the problem with my calculations. Is it the lookAt()? or the perspective()? or is it everything?

Comment: I don't think you actually do have this correct. Unrelated to handedness, OpenGL (historically) expects matrix memory to be arranged in column-major form. You have your ModelView matrix transposed assuming you have not told OpenGL to use a different representation in GLSL. You can actually have the call to `glUniformMatrix4fv (...)` perform transposition by changing `GL_FALSE` to `GL_TRUE`; not the ideal approach, but quickest way to test for that problem.

Comment: the model matrix is just the identity matrix for right now so it shouldnt be what is causing the problem.